Trouble Capturing All Tick Data with Concurrent.futures in Python
I am developing a program to insert tick-level data for 300+ stocks received in a webstream dictionary format from a broker API. I successfully have a version of the program running without concurrent.futures, but it misses some ticks due to the high-speed arrival of data.
In the new version where I incorporated concurrent.futures, I face an issue where various ticks are being missed and not captured in my MySQL database. The ticks arrive at super-fast speeds, and the queue size gets filled quickly, leading to missed ticks.
Here’s my approach to solve this issue with multiprocessing, using the concurrent.futures library. I am a newbie to multiprocessing, and I aim to capture at least 1 tick per second per stock for 500+ stocks.
Current Issues:
The queue size gets filled quickly, and ticks are missed.
At least 5-10 ticks per 10 seconds per stock are missed, making the data incomplete for decent analytical charts.
Expectation:
Capture (in the MySQL table) at least 1 tick per second per stock for 500+ stocks.
Complete Program:
from kiteconnect import KiteTicker, KiteConnect
import datetime
import sys
import pandas as pd
import os
from os import cpu_count
import mysql.connector
import time as tm
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
import queue
import threading

# Change working directory
cwd = os.chdir(r"D:\Trading\Algo Trading\ZERODHA ALGO\account_auth")

# Generate trading session
access_token = open("access_token.txt", 'r').read()
key_secret = open("api_key.txt", 'r').read().split()
kite = KiteConnect(api_key=key_secret[0])
kite.set_access_token(access_token)

# Read MySQL password
mysql_password = open("mysql_pwd.txt", 'r').read()

# MySQL database credentials
db_config = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'user': 'root',
    'password': mysql_password,
    'database': 'ZerodhaAlgoTest'
}

def create_tables(tokens):
    db = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
    c = db.cursor(buffered=True)
    for token in tokens:
        c.execute(f"""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TOKEN{token} (
                ts DATETIME PRIMARY KEY,
                price DECIMAL(20, 5),
                volume BIGINT,
                total_buy_quantity BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
                total_sell_quantity BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
                volume_consecutive BIGINT DEFAULT 0
            )
        """)
        columns = {
            'total_buy_quantity': 'BIGINT DEFAULT 0',
            'total_sell_quantity': 'BIGINT DEFAULT 0',
            'volume_consecutive': 'BIGINT DEFAULT 0'
        }
        for col_name, col_type in columns.items():
            c.execute(f"""
                SELECT column_name
                FROM information_schema.columns
                WHERE table_name = 'TOKEN{token}' AND column_name = '{col_name}'
            """)
            if not c.fetchone():
                c.execute(f"ALTER TABLE TOKEN{token} ADD COLUMN {col_name} {col_type}")

    db.commit()
    db.close()

def tokenLookup(instrument_df, symbol_list):
    token_list = []
    for symbol in symbol_list:
        try:
            token_list.append(int(instrument_df[instrument_df.tradingsymbol == symbol].instrument_token.values[0]))
        except:
            print(f'Ticker - {symbol} not found in the instrument list of NSE')
    return token_list

def symbolLookup(instrument_df, token_list):
    symbol_list = []
    for token in token_list:
        try:
            symbol_list.append(instrument_df[instrument_df.instrument_token == token].tradingsymbol.values[0])
        except:
            print(f'Token - {token} not found in the instrument list of NSE')
    return symbol_list

# Load the instrument dataframe globally
instrument_df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\Trading\Algo Trading\ZERODHA ALGO\account_auth\Total_instrument_df.xlsx")
instrument_df = instrument_df[instrument_df['exchange'].isin(['NSE', 'NFO'])]

tickersDf = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Trading\Algo Trading\ZERODHA ALGO\ticks_instruments_list.xlsx')
print('tickers read from file...')
tickers = tickersDf['SYMBOL'].tolist()

def insert_ticks(tick):
    db = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
    c = db.cursor()
    if 'exchange_timestamp' not in tick:
        print(f"Skipping tick with missing 'exchange_timestamp': {tick['instrument_token']}")
        return
    
    tok = "TOKEN" + str(tick['instrument_token'])
    symbol = symbolLookup(instrument_df, [tick['instrument_token']])[0]
    vals = [
        tick['exchange_timestamp'],
        tick['last_price'],
        tick['last_traded_quantity'],
        tick.get('total_buy_quantity', 0),
        tick.get('total_sell_quantity', 0),
        tick.get('volume_traded', 0),
        symbol
    ]    
    token_query = f"""
    INSERT INTO {tok} (ts, price, volume, total_buy_quantity, total_sell_quantity, volume_consecutive)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    price = VALUES(price),
    volume = VALUES(volume),
    total_buy_quantity = VALUES(total_buy_quantity),
    total_sell_quantity = VALUES(total_sell_quantity),
    volume_consecutive = VALUES(volume_consecutive)
    """
    try:
        c.execute(token_query, vals[:-1])
        print(f'Tick inserted into - {symbol}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Tick data error for - {tok}: {e}')
    db.commit()
    db.close()

def is_time_between(start_hour, start_minute, end_hour, end_minute):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    start_time = now.replace(hour=start_hour, minute=start_minute, second=0, microsecond=0)
    end_time = now.replace(hour=end_hour, minute=end_minute, second=0, microsecond=0)
    return start_time <= now <= end_time

def worker(data_queue, stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set() or not data_queue.empty():
        try:
            tick = data_queue.get(timeout=0.1)
            insert_ticks(tick)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tokens = tokenLookup(instrument_df, tickers)
    create_tables(tokens)
    print('Tables created and new columns added')

    data_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=90000)
    stop_event = threading.Event()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count()) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(worker, data_queue, stop_event) for _ in range(cpu_count())]
        
        def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
            for tick in ticks:
                try:
                    data_queue.put(tick, timeout=0.1)
                except queue.Full:
                    print(f"Queue is full. Skipping tick: {tick['instrument_token']}")
            print(f"Ticks added to queue, current queue size: {data_queue.qsize()}")

        def on_connect(ws, response):
            ws.subscribe(tokens)
            ws.set_mode(ws.MODE_FULL, tokens)

        def on_error(ws, code, reason):
            print(f"WebSocket error: {code} - {reason}")

        kws = KiteTicker(key_secret[0], kite.access_token)
        kws.on_ticks = on_ticks
        kws.on_connect = on_connect
        kws.on_error = on_error

        is_connected = False
        try:
            while True:
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                if is_time_between(8, 59, 23, 30):
                    if not is_connected:
                        print('Ticks started now...at {}'.format(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
                        kws.connect()
                        is_connected = True
                else:
                    if is_connected:
                        kws.unsubscribe()
                        print('Exiting script...')
                        stop_event.set()
                        break
                tm.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            stop_event.set()
            print('Script interrupted and stopped.')

        for future in as_completed(futures):
            future.result()

        print("All tasks completed.")
        sys.exit()

Specific Questions:
How can I prevent the queue from getting filled quickly and missing ticks?
Are there any improvements or best practices I should consider to handle high-speed data insertion using concurrent.futures and multiprocessing?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please fix your indentation and reduce the code to a Minimal Reproducible Example You will probably want to rewrite your insert_ticks() function so that you're not continually opening and closing the DB connection.

You are also missing required import statement and/or class definitions. Youi say, "I already have this program run successfully without trying to implement multiprocessing through concurrent.futures library." If it were running successfully you would not be missing ticks or needing to use multiprocessing.

Hi @Booboo
I have edited the complete post for further clarity. I already have another version of this program without concurrent.futures(multiprocessing concepts) which produces just okay results of inserting ticks every 10 seconds per stock.
My expectation is to capture 1 tick per second per stock.

Hi @SIGHUP
I have edited the complete post. Now you can find the complete program here. Earlier I had given just the relevant functions.
Thanks

How is it that you are using a queue.Queue instance and a threading.Event instance with a multiprocessing pool? You should create the DB connection once in worker and then pass db as an argument to insert_ticks.

You can't use queue.Queue and a threading.Event instance with a multiprocessing pool. Here are some suggestions:
I would first try to using a multithreading pool since your worker function is mostly waiting on your data base to complete its insert operation. I would also create the DB connection once for each pool thread and get rid of the event variable and instead have the main thread insert into the queue a special sentinel value that signals the worker to terminate when it is retrieved. insert_tick becomes:
def insert_ticks(db, tick):
    # We are passed the database connection
    c = db.cursor()
    ...
    #db.close()  # Do not close the connection
    c.close()

worker becomes:
def worker(data_queue):
    db = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)

    while True:
        tick = data_queue.get()
        if tick is None:  # Sentinel value to terminate
            break
        insert_ticks(db, tick)  # Pass db

    db.close()

Finally,
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tokens = tokenLookup(instrument_df, tickers)
    create_tables(tokens)
    print('Tables created and new columns added')

    data_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=90000)
    pool_size = cpu_count()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=pool_size) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(worker, data_queue) for _ in range(pool_size)]

        ...

          except KeyboardInterrupt:
            for _ in range(pool_size):
                data_queue.put(None)  # single each thread to terminate
            print('Script interrupted and stopped.')

You may need to experiment with the pool_size value for optimal results.

Hi @Booboo,
Thanks for your neat response. I will implement these changes and test the results during Monday's market session.

I have updated the answer because I inadvertently left the code using a ProcessPoolExecutor instead of a ThreadPoolExecutor. which is what you now need to import.

On my desktop where I am doing SELECT statements instead of INSERT statements, my optimal pool size is 2. Your biggest performance boost might come from not creating a connection for each insertion.

Hi @Booboo
I had seen that already and changed accordingly in my program.
I ran the program today and experimented with - 2,3,4,12,24 pool_size(I have 12 cpu cores)
Looks like pool_size = 24 seems to work for me. Though I still dont get 1 tick per second per stock every time but the results are quite better. I will continue to experiment further for the next few days.

Also I noticed that somebody has closed my question.
We need to be considerate with people in stackoverflow. While targeting for perfection is good but not everyone can post a FLAWLESS SPOTLESS question everytime.
I had tried really hard to improve the question with better sentences and I think the moderators are a bit harsh as usual on stackoverflow.com

Hi @Booboo
Your replies helped me to arrive at a much better solution. Thanks I have marked your reply as the Answer.

I am still doing some more testing as I found out that still ticks are being missed for some stocks. I would probably need to try with different values of pool_size.

You might want to have a single table with an additional column named symbol. And then have worker accumulate N ticks for some suitable value of N and then pass to insert_ticks a list of ticks to be inserted with executemany. The idea is that doing a single executemany with a list of N lists should be more efficient than doing N separate execute statements.
